# the letters abcdefgh are to be used to form strings of length 5. How many strings contain the letter a if repetions are allowed?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

the letters ABCDEFGH are to be used to form strings of length 5. How many strings contain the letter a if repetitions are allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: How many strings doesn't contain the letter A?

Comment: You're sure that there are $8^5$ strings with all $8$ letters (and that is correct), but not that there are $7^5$ with only $7$? Why wouldn't there be, the situation is the same. - In other words: Yes, there are $7^5$ strngs without the letter A.

Comment: That's what I get too. But there's no reason to assume I'm any better at entering that into a calculator than you are.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the best way is to find how many string doen't contain A and subtract it from total i.e., $ 8^5 - 7^5 $

The other method is: find no. strings that has exactly 1 A :  ${5 \choose 1} * 7^4$.

Then no. of string which has exactly two A :  ${5 \choose 2} * 7^3$ and so on.

Thus, total no. of such strings would be = $({5 \choose 1} * 7^4 + {5 \choose 2} * 7^3 + {5 \choose 3} * 7^2 + {5 \choose 4} * 7^1 + {5 \choose 5} * 7^0)$

which equals to   $15961$

Answer (score 0):

You are halfway there.  Now some of the strings do not contain A.  How many strings are there that don't contain A?  Subtract them from $8^5$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

In general, among the very first things you should look at for counting problems is to look at the negation: in this case, how many strings *don't* contain `a`?